# Duplicating Div always duplicates

Tags: javascript

**TO BETTER UNDERSTAND MY QUESTION AND SEE CODE VISIT THE FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dnyXC/**

I have a script (below) that allows you to click a icon and it duplicates the table allowing for more inputs on the included form. This issue is, once you click the icon once to duplicate it, anywhere you click on the table regardless of position duplicates the table again.

```
document.getElementById('line-duplicate').onclick = duplicate;
    var i = 0;

        function duplicate() {
            var original = document.getElementById('item-table' + i);
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
            clone.id = "item-table" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
            clone.onclick = duplicate; // event handlers are not cloned
            original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
        }
```

Here is the html for the table:

```
<table class="table" id="item-table0">
<tr>
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>Qty/Hrs</td>
    <td>Rate</td>
    <td>Tax Rate</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="input-medium" type="text" name="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="input-mini" type="text" name="" placeholder="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="input-mini" type="text" name="" placeholder="0.00" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <select class="input-small" name="">
            <option>Standard</option>
            <option>Expense</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>$0.00</td>
    <td><i class="icon-plus" style="cursor:pointer;" id="line-duplicate"></i>  <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

endless duplication is fine, the issue is when you go to type another item into the form, you duplicate the table. I need it so that the only way to duplicate the table is by clicking the plus icon.

**TO BETTER UNDERSTAND MY QUESTION AND SEE CODE VISIT THE FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dnyXC/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are binding the `onclick` for the entire duplicated row to the `duplicate()` function.

You should make `line-duplicate` a class (having multiple elements with the same ID is a bad thing), and use `document.getElementsByClassName('line-duplicate')` both inside and outside the function to bind the duplicate function to every single element with that class name, like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('line-duplicate')[0].onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;

function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('item-table' + i);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "item-table" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    var listOfLineDuplicateItems = document.getElementsByClassName('line-duplicate'); // this must be after the table has been appended to the DOM
    for (var j = 0; j < listOfLineDuplicateItems.length; ++j) {
        listOfLineDuplicateItems[i].onclick = duplicate;
    }
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dnyXC/1/)

Comment: Nothing happens. I A.) changed the id to a class and B.) copied and pasted the script above into the project. And now nothing copies?

Comment: Hello? Did you get that last comment?

Comment: @user2371301 Yes I did, and I think I fixed it. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dnyXC/1/

Comment: @user2371301 There were two problems - I was using the variable names twice, so stuff got overidden, and after changing `id` to `class` there were two `class` attributes, so the `line-duplicate` class wasn't registered...

Comment: Thank you oh so very much! Now time to research how to delete them if need be. But thank you for answering this question.

Comment: @user2371301 No worries :)